# how to clear tkinter widgets on a canvas then add more widgets afterwards?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I want to add a restart function to my option chooser and first it neeeds to clear the screen, but that's what i can't figure out. everything else is fine it's just the clearing i need help with. the code for the restart function yes I know it is a lot

this is the code for the canvas do i need to add anything to it to make the canvas.delete to work?

```
# Creating a canvas
win = Canvas(window, bg="white", height=900, width=900)
win.pack()
```

and this is the area where i need to clear the canvas

```
def start_again():

    def display_answer2():
        entry = choice_entry3.get()
        match entry:
            case "0":
                output = Label(win,
                               text="Then why are you here? dang either you're old or you're trying to make this\n "
                                    "program go koo KOO! Thankfully my developer actually cared to put this safety\n "
                                    "mechanism IN!.",
                               font="Courier 9 bold")
                output.pack()
                restart()
            case "1":
                opt_1_entry = Entry(win, width=40)
                opt_1_entry.focus_set()
                opt_1_entry.pack()

                def output_answer():
                    output1 = Label(win,
                                    text="Uh-hh " + opt_1_entry.get() + "?? I dunno, what do you want? You only gave "
                                                                        "me one, dang you\n"
                                                                        "really want my program head to explode "
                                                                        "don't YOU!? ",
                                    font="Courier 9 bold")
                    output1.pack()
                    restart()

                tk.Button(win, text="GO!", width=20, command=output_answer).pack(pady=20)
            case "2":
                opt_1_entry = Entry(win, width=40)
                opt_1_entry.focus_set()
                opt_1_entry.pack()
                opt_2_entry = Entry(win, width=40)
                opt_2_entry.focus_set()
                opt_2_entry.pack()

                def output_answer2():
                    opt_1 = opt_1_entry.get()
                    opt_2 = opt_2_entry.get()
                    choice_list = [opt_1, opt_2]
                    random_choice = choice(choice_list)
                    ai_random_choice = str(random_choice)
                    output2 = Label(win, text="THE AI HAS SPOKEN YOUR CHOICE SHALL BE " + ai_random_choice + ".",
                                    font="Courier 9 bold")
                    output2.pack()
                    tk.Button(win, text="Restart?", width=20, command=start_again).pack(pady=20)
                    tk.Button(win, text="exit?", width=20, command=win.quit).pack(pady=20)

                tk.Button(win, text="GO!", width=20, command=output_answer2).pack(pady=20)
        # Initialize a Label to display the User Input
        instructions3 = Label(win, text="type in how many decisions you                 have (max 10) \n↓\n", font="Courier 14 bold")
        instructions3.pack()

        # Create an Entry widget to accept User Input
        choice_entry3 = Entry(win, width=40)
        choice_entry3.focus_set()
        choice_entry3.pack()
```

Comment: There is no code related to a `Canvas`.  It is not clear what your issue is.

Comment: `the_canvas.delete("all")` will delete everything on a canvas.

Comment: Yes there is i will add it now

Comment: ok i tried that but it is still not working

Comment: "still not working" is not very helpful.  You wouldn't tell your mechanic "the car isn't working".  Without seeing your code, you could have done a hundred things wrong.  Note that in some cases, it can be easier just to create a new main window.

Comment: Adding widgets to a canvas using tkinter layout functions, `pack()` or `grid()` or `place()`, cannot be removed by `canvas.delete("all")`.  You need to use `canvas.create_window()` to add those widgets into the canvas.